# asp.net - object reference not set to an instance of an object for master page cs file

Tags: asp.net

This is the code to my Master Page cs file. For some reason when I run my default page, I get an error that says "object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Theming.MasterPages
{
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string selectedTheme = Page.Theme;
            HttpCookie preferredTheme = Request.Cookies.Get("PreferredTheme");
            if (preferredTheme != null)
            {
                selectedTheme = preferredTheme.Value;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedTheme))
            {
                ListItem item = ThemeList.Items.FindByValue(selectedTheme);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        switch (Page.Theme.ToLower())
        {
            case "darkgrey":
                Menu1.Visible = false;
                TreeView1.Visible = true;
                break;
            default:
                Menu1.Visible = true;
                TreeView1.Visible = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void ThemeList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie preferredTheme = new HttpCookie("PreferredTheme");
        preferredTheme.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
        preferredTheme.Value = ThemeList.SelectedValue;
        Response.Cookies.Add(preferredTheme);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
     }
  }
}
```

The error appears to be at the switch statement but I can't figure out why. I've read on other posts that the value is assigning to the variable as null but I don't know why; I've got dark grey as an app theme. If anyone could please help me it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: When you debug are you able to fall into the darkgrey case? Can you show any markup for your MasterPage? That would help with diagnosis. My guess is that Menu1 or TreeView1 are null when you try to call .Visible. This is causing your issue.

Comment: <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.master.cs" Inherits="Theming.MasterPages.Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="PageWrapper">
      <header><a href="/"></a></header>
      <nav>

Comment: <asp:TreeNodeStyle CssClass="FirstLevelMenuItems" />
          </LevelStyles>
        </asp:TreeView>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" />
      </nav>
      <section id="MainContent">
        <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server"></asp:SiteMapPath><br /><br />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpMainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </section>
      <aside id="Sidebar">
        Select a theme<br />

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ThemeList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ThemeList_SelectedIndexChanged">
          <asp:ListItem>Monochrome</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>DarkGrey</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: <br />
          <br />
      </aside>
      <footer>Footer Goes Here</footer>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Had to break it up into bits and pieces because of character limitations :(

Comment: No worries. Next time just edit the original post 

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `Menu1` or `TreeView1` defined anywhere in your markup. If those are in a content page, you can't access those in the MasterPage code-behind (there may be a way, but you can't directly access them the way you're trying to).

Comment: This is in the Main.master file after the first nav:

Comment: <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="MainMenu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"></asp:Menu>
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" ShowExpandCollapse="False">

Comment: I guess this accidentally got left off

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, set a break point inside of the switch and see if it gets hit. Work backward from there.

Comment: The problem appears to be fixed, I remade my site map and it seems to have produced a good effect.